# Extract exact matching strings using 'grep'

Tags: bash, shell

I try to extract files with extension `.mkv` from `mkv.md` with `grep`

```
    $ grep -i 'mkv' mkv.md
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
    ...
```

There's a leading period in the output which should be removed manually. 
the result I desire is (without period symbol)

```
    /Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
    /Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
    /Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
```

I tried and get the same result.

```
    grep -i '\/.*\.mkv' mkv.md
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
    ./Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
    ...
```

How to solve the problem?

Comment: What is the content of `mkv.md`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-o`
-o, --only-matching :Prints only the matching part of the lines.

In your example:

```
grep -io '\/.*\.mkv' mkv.md
#please note that you can combine multiple options as the above, or
grep -i -o '\/.*\.mkv' mkv.md
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use other commands, cut can help:

```
$ grep -i mkv mkv.md | cut -c 2-
/Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep4.mkv
/Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep5.mkv
/Volumes/Transcend/Downloads/The.Adventure.of.English.Ep6.mkv
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cut** :

`cut -c 2-` - cuts from second character to end of the string

In you example :

```
grep -i 'mkv' mkv.md | cut -c 2-
```

More examples here : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)